# Getting memory leak but memory allocated was deallocated

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks

C noob over here. Created a program that simulates a soccer team to help me get a handle on memory allocation. My program works but valgrind is telling me that I have a memory leak in the methods "create_player" and "add_player_to_club"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 8

typedef struct player {
    int id;
    char *position;
} Player;

typedef struct club {
    int size;
    Player *team[SIZE];
} Club;


Player *create_player(int id, const char *description);
void create_team(Club *club);
void print_club(const Club *club);
void destroy_player(Player *player);
void add_player_to_club(Club *club, int id, const char *position);
void destroy_club(Club *club);

int main() {
    Club club;

    create_team(&club);
    add_player_to_club(&club, 1, "forward");
    add_player_to_club(&club, 2, "goalie");
    print_club(&club);
    destroy_club(&club);

    return 0;
}

Player *create_player(int id, const char *description){

    Player *player;

    player = malloc(sizeof(Player));

    if(description == NULL){
        player->position = NULL;

    } else {
        player->position = malloc(strlen(description) + 1);
        strcpy(player->position, description);
        player->id = id;
    }
    return player;
}
void destroy_player(Player *player){

    if (player == NULL){
        return;
    } else {
        free(player->position);
        free(player);
    }
}


void create_team(Club *team){

    team->size = 0;

}
void print_club(const Club *club) {

    int i = 0;

    if (club == NULL) {
        return;
    } else if (club->size == 0) {
        printf("No team members\n");
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < club->size; i++) {
            printf("Id: %d Position: %s\n", club->team[i]->id,
                   club->team[i]->position);
        }
    }
}
void add_player_to_club(Club *club, int id, const char *position){


    if (club == NULL || club->size >= SIZE) {
        return;
    } else {
        club->team[club->size] = create_player(id, position);
        club->size++;

    }
}
void destroy_club(Club *club){

    int i = 0;

    if (club == NULL) {
        return;
    } else {
        club->size = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < club->size; i++) {

            destroy_player(club->team[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem might be with my "destroy club" method. Player "objects" are stored in the "team" array. I allocated memory for each player object and deallocating by iterating through team array and freeing each index. What did I screw up?

Comment: `club->size = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < club->size; i++) {` What.

Comment: Follow-up of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126544/printing-fields-of-structure-in-c-dynamic-memory-allocation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `destroy_club`, you set `size` to 0, then use that to loop through the players, so it loops through nothing.

Set `size` to 0 *after* cleaning up the players:

```
    for (i = 0; i < club->size; i++) {

        destroy_player(club->team[i]);
    }

    club->size = 0;
```